# Pandas Python, how to search a column to check if it contains a certain string value so it returns a value in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, wildcard

I have a data set in python of different products. The columns = Product Name; Cost, Size etc:. Within the ProductName column contains the colour e.g., Toy Car (Green).

I want to create a new column that based on the colour in the  ProductName column, it will return a colour ID number.

```
Prod Name      | Colour ID
Toy Car(Green) |     3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help those who want to help you could you show the two dataframes you are trying to merge? Also, does the Pandas Documentation on [Comparison with SQL](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html) help at all?

Comment: It's difficult to provide a good answer without a more precise statement. For instance, are the colors always in `()`, and is it possible there could be other non-color information contained in brackets?

Comment: Yes all colours are contained in brackets and there is no non-color information in the brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have a dictionary that map the product color name to the specific number.

```
my_dict = {"Green": 3, "Blue": 2, "Red": 1}
```

So, the following code must convert the product name to numbers for you:

```
def convert_color_to_number(product_name):
    for color in my_dict.keys():
        if color in product_name:
            return my_dict[color]
    return 0

df[["Colour ID"] = df["Prod Name"].apply(lambda x: convert_color_to_number(x))
```